# Making pyplot.hist() first and last bins include outliers

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

`pyplot.hist()` documentation specifies that when setting a range for a histogram *"lower and upper outliers are ignored"*.

Is it possible to make the first and last bins of a histogram include all outliers *without changing the width of the bin*?

For example, let's say I want to look at the range `0-3` with 3 bins: `0-1, 1-2, 2-3` (let's ignore cases of exact equality for simplicity). I would like the first bin to include all values from minus infinity to 1, and the last bin to include all values from 2 to infinity. However, if I explicitly set these bins to span that range, they will be very wide. I would like them to have the same width. The behavior I am looking for is like the behavior of `hist()` in Matlab.

Obviously I can `numpy.clip()` the data and plot that, which will give me what I want. But I am interested if there is a builtin solution for this.

Comment: Sounds like you have a two-line solution (`numpy.clip(); pyplot.hist()`) and you'd want a one-liner. While I guess a `clip` keyword to `hist()` would be nice, I think no-one has bothered to implement this because it's so basic. Of course, you could always submit a patch to matplotlib :-).

Comment: Yes, @Evert is right, clip is the best solution.  I would say that `pyplot.hist()` does not build this in probably because it generates  misleading plots if not carefully annotated.

Comment: @Evert ok, thanks. I just wanted to see that I am not missing some better solution to get this behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Looking at `matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist` and the direct use of `numpy.histogram` I'm fairly confident in saying that there is no smarter solution than using clip (other than extending the bins that you histogram with).

I'd encourage you to look at the source of `matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist` (it's just Python code, though admittedly hist is slightly more complex than most of the Axes methods) - it is **the** best way to verify this kind of question.

Answer (score 15):

I was also struggling with this, and didn't want to use `.clip()` because it could be misleading, so I wrote a little function (borrowing heavily from [this](https://edwinth.github.io/blog/outlier-bin/)) to indicate that the upper and lower bins contained outliers:

```
def outlier_aware_hist(data, lower=None, upper=None):
    if not lower or lower < data.min():
        lower = data.min()
        lower_outliers = False
    else:
        lower_outliers = True

    if not upper or upper > data.max():
        upper = data.max()
        upper_outliers = False
    else:
        upper_outliers = True

    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, range=(lower, upper), bins='auto')

    if lower_outliers:
        n_lower_outliers = (data < lower).sum()
        patches[0].set_height(patches[0].get_height() + n_lower_outliers)
        patches[0].set_facecolor('c')
        patches[0].set_label('Lower outliers: ({:.2f}, {:.2f})'.format(data.min(), lower))

    if upper_outliers:
        n_upper_outliers = (data > upper).sum()
        patches[-1].set_height(patches[-1].get_height() + n_upper_outliers)
        patches[-1].set_facecolor('m')
        patches[-1].set_label('Upper outliers: ({:.2f}, {:.2f})'.format(upper, data.max()))

    if lower_outliers or upper_outliers:
        plt.legend()
```

You can also combine it with an automatic outlier detector (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882393/matplotlib-disregard-outliers-when-plotting)) like so:

```
def mad(data):
    median = np.median(data)
    diff = np.abs(data - median)
    mad = np.median(diff)
    return mad

def calculate_bounds(data, z_thresh=3.5):
    MAD = mad(data)
    median = np.median(data)
    const = z_thresh * MAD / 0.6745
    return (median - const, median + const)

outlier_aware_hist(data, *calculate_bounds(data))
```

[image: Generated data from a standard normal and then added some outliers. Plots with and without outlier binning.]

Comment: Nice, I stole it. However, I think you have to be aware when using it that the first and last bin of the histogram includes the outliers. it is not a separate pot for outliers

Answer (score 0):

What `pyplot.hist` is doing can be separated into 2 steps: calculating the distribution for the histogram and then plotting a bar chart with it. Maybe the easiest way to achieve what you want is doing the first step with `numpy.histogram` and using `pyplot.bar` directly for the second:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dummy data
rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = rng.normal(loc=1, scale=0.5, size=1000)
bins = np.linspace(0,2, 11)

fig = plt.figure(layout='tight')
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.set_xticks(bins)

# In order to include outliers, expand the bins with -Inf and +Inf before calculating the distribution.
bins_expanded = np.concatenate([[-np.inf],bins,[np.inf]])
dist, _ = np.histogram(x, bins_expanded)

# Then, use the original bins to plot the bar chart
# Here, I made it such that the outliers are plotted as separate bars on the outmost bins.
width = bins[1]-bins[0]
ax.bar(bins[0], dist[0], bottom=dist[1], align='edge', width=width, color='red', edgecolor='black', label='left outliers')
ax.bar(bins[:-1],dist[1:-1], align='edge', width=width, color='blue', edgecolor='black', label='distribution')
ax.bar(bins[-2],dist[-1], bottom=dist[-2], align='edge', width=width, color='green', edgecolor='black', label='right_outliers')

ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```