# median-absolute-deviation (MAD) based outlier detection

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I wanted to apply median-absolute-deviation (MAD) based outlier detection using the answer from @Joe Kington as given below:

[Pythonic way of detecting outliers in one dimensional observation data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354094/pythonic-way-of-detecting-outliers-in-one-dimensional-observation-data)

However, what's going wrong with my code, I could not figure out how to assign the outliers as nan values for MY DATA:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([55,32,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,0,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,25,25,25,25,10,11,12,25,26,27,28],dtype=float)
median = np.median(data, axis=0)
diff = np.sum((data - median)**2, axis=-1)
diff = np.sqrt(diff)
med_abs_deviation = np.median(diff)
modified_z_score = 0.6745 * diff / med_abs_deviation
data_without_outliers = data[modified_z_score < 3.5]
?????
print data_without_outliers
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem with using:

```
data[modified_z_score > 3.5] = np.nan
```

Note that this will only work if `data` is a floating point array (which it should be if you are calculating MAD).

Comment: You may want to be more explicit and set the `dtype` to either `"float32"` or `np.float32`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be line:

`diff = np.sum((data - median)**2, axis=-1)`

Applying np.sum() will collapse the result to scalar.
Remove top-level sum, and your code will work.
Other way around it to ensure that that `data` is at least 2d array. You can use numpy.atleast_2d() for that.

In order to assign NaNs, follow answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22804327/4989451