# Detect and exclude outliers in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, dataframe, outliers

I have a pandas dataframe with few columns.
Now I know that certain rows are outliers based on a certain column value.
For instance
column `Vol` has all values around 12xx and one value is 4000 (outlier).
I would like to exclude those rows that have `Vol` column like this.

So, essentially I need to put a filter on the data frame such that we select all rows where the values of a certain column are within, say, 3 standard deviations from mean.

What is an elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 432):

### Use [`scipy.stats.zscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html)

#### Remove all rows that have outliers in at least one column

If you have multiple columns in your dataframe and would like to remove all rows that have outliers in at least one column, the following expression would do that in one shot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3))

df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```

##### Description:

- For each column, it first computes the Z-score of each value in the
  column, relative to the column mean and standard deviation.
- It then takes the absolute Z-score because the direction does not
  matter, only if it is below the threshold.
- `( < 3).all(axis=1)` checks if, for each row, all column values are within 3 standard deviations from the mean
- Finally, the result of this condition is used to index the dataframe.

#### Filter other columns based on a single column

The same as above, but specify a column for the `zscore`, `df[0]` for example, and remove `.all(axis=1)`.

```py
df[np.abs(stats.zscore(df[0])) < 3]
```

Comment: How would you handle the situation when there are Nulls/Nans in the columns. 
How can we have them ignored ?

Comment: how do we deal with str columns for this solution? If some of the columns are non-numeric and we want to remove outliers based on all numeric columns.

Comment: @rafaelvalle What is the significance of 3 in the code above, can you explain that?

Comment: assuming distribution X with mean mu and standard deviation sigma, the z score measures how many sigmas a value is from mu. algebraically: z-score = (x - mu) / sigma. the 3 is the threshold in number of standard deviations away from the mean.

Comment: Succinct and elegant for all dataset's attributes. I like it. I have taken the liberty to extend your answer (see bellow) to handle a data-frame than might contain also non-numerical values. Hope it can help someone.

Comment: Got error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'"

Comment: @sak : that is because you are running this on all columns and rows in your dataset.  so, it expects these values to be numeric.  typically you can execute the above by column name, or first apply (one-hot?) encoding to make all your values numeric, before executing this.

Comment: @tanemaki - I also use this code for the outliers, but I am now looking to get the list of columns that contain values that fall outside of the 3-sigma range.  so I can use this to scan a dataset and get a good indication of which columns contain outliers.

Comment: @rafaelvalle. Should we use all or any?

Comment: This fails in the event that an entire column has the same value - in these cases zscore returns NaN and therefore the < 3 check returns False for every row, so it drops every record.

Comment: It's better to explicitly state the axis: `df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df, axis=0)) < 3).all(axis=1)]`

Comment: @tanemaki I made boxplot graphs before and after using that command (in jupyter notebook, it shows you q1, q3, upper fence, lower_fence). Checking my results after using that command, I have fewer records, but some of them would still be outliers because their values are higher than upper_fence or lower than lower_fence from my original boxplot. Do you know why that happens? Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell me what number 3 represents in df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 3).all(axis=1)]
?

Comment: The number 3 represent the 3 standard deviation. You can find more information about it here: https://sixsigmastudyguide.com/z-scores-z-table-z-transformations/

Comment: @sak : if some numbers are wrongly read as strings, you can try this: DF["column"] = pd.to_numeric(DF["column"])   . It will transform strings to numbers, if they contains numbers of course.

Comment: Is there a way to use this for multiple columns, but not all?

Comment: I think I did it df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df[['column_1', 'column_2']])) < 3).all(axis=1)]

Comment: No need to use `np.abs`, Pandas has that built in. Plus you can use `.lt()` instead of `<` to get cleaner chaining. `df[stats.zscore(df).abs().lt(3).all(axis=1)]`

Answer (score 243):

For each of your dataframe column, you could get quantile with:

```
q = df["col"].quantile(0.99)
```

and then filter with:

```
df[df["col"] < q]
```

If one need to remove lower and upper outliers, combine condition with an AND statement:

```
q_low = df["col"].quantile(0.01)
q_hi  = df["col"].quantile(0.99)

df_filtered = df[(df["col"] < q_hi) & (df["col"] > q_low)]
```

Comment: This article gives a very good overview of outlier removal techniques https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-statistics-to-identify-outliers-in-data/

Comment: this might remove outliers only from upper bound.. not lower?

Comment: @indolentdeveloper you are right, just invert the inequality to remove lower outliers, or combine them with an OR operator.

Comment: @user6903745 AND statement or "OR"?

Comment: @A.B yes that's an AND statement, mistake in my previous comment

Comment: @user6903745 df_filtered = df[(df["col"] < q_hi) & (df["col"] > q_low)]
I guess this statement is enough to remove both upper and lower outliers. I don't know why this isn't enough

Comment: for those who have 10k of data and just a dozen outliers , quantile doesn't help. I'd suggest z-score

Comment: @user6903745 when you have a few thousands of 0s and 1s in a series of 10.000 values and like only 20-30 values above 1 , you need quantiles like 0.9999 to see something different

Comment: @kommradHomer I agree, it might depend on the shape of the data distribution

Answer (score 192):

Use `boolean` indexing as you would do in `numpy.array`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':np.random.normal(size=200)})
# example dataset of normally distributed data. 

df[np.abs(df.Data-df.Data.mean()) <= (3*df.Data.std())]
# keep only the ones that are within +3 to -3 standard deviations in the column 'Data'.

df[~(np.abs(df.Data-df.Data.mean()) > (3*df.Data.std()))]
# or if you prefer the other way around
```

For a series it is similar:

```
S = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=200))
S[~((S-S.mean()).abs() > 3*S.std())]
```

Comment: their is a ``DataFrame.abs()`` FYI, also ``DataFrame.clip()``

Comment: In the case of `clip()`, Jeff, the outlines are not removed: `df.SOME_DATA.clip(-3std,+3std)` assign the outliners to either +3std or -3std

Comment: What if i need hte same on a pd.Series?

Comment: That is almost the same, @AMM

Comment: How can we do the same thing if our pandas data frame has 100 columns?

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that answer @CTZhu. @DreamerP you can just apply it to the whole DataFrame with: `df_new = df[np.abs(df - df.mean()) <= (3 * df.std())]`. **But** in contrast to applying it to a Series or single column, this will replace outliers with `np.nan` and keep the shape of the DataFrame, so interpolation might be needed to fill the missing values.

Comment: I get "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Data' ". Anyone know how to tackle this?

Comment: @enricw That means your dataframe has no column named `'Data'`, you'll need to select the column with the right name for *you*.

Answer (score 54):

Before answering the actual question we should ask another one that's very relevant depending on the nature of your data:

## What is an outlier?

Imagine the series of values `[3, 2, 3, 4, 999]` (where the `999` seemingly doesn't fit in) and analyse various ways of outlier detection

### Z-Score

The problem here is that the value in question distorts our measures `mean` and `std` heavily, resulting in inconspicious z-scores of roughly `[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 2.0]`, keeping every value within two standard deviations of the mean. One very large outlier might hence distort your whole assessment of outliers. I would discourage this approach.

### Quantile Filter

A way more robust approach is given is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093390/3104974), eliminating the bottom and top 1% of data. However, this eliminates a fixed fraction independant of the question if these data are really outliers. You might loose a lot of valid data, and on the other hand still keep some outliers if you have more than 1% or 2% of your data as outliers.

### IQR-distance from Median

Even more robust version of the quantile principle: Eliminate all data that is more than `f` times the [*interquartile range*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range) away from the *median* of the data. That's also the transformation that `sklearn`'s [`RobustScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html) uses for example. IQR and median are robust to outliers, so you outsmart the problems of the z-score approach.

In a normal distribution, we have roughly `iqr=1.35*s`, so you would translate `z=3` of a z-score filter to `f=2.22` of an iqr-filter. This will drop the `999` in the above example.

The basic assumption is that at least the "middle half" of your data is valid and resembles the distribution well, whereas you also mess up if your distribution has wide tails and a narrow q_25% to q_75% interval.

### Advanced Statistical Methods

Of course there are fancy mathematical methods like the [Peirce criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_criterion), [Grubb's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grubbs%27s_test) or [Dixon's Q-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_Q_test) just to mention a few that are also suitable for non-normally distributed data. None of them are easily implemented and hence not addressed further.

## Code

Replacing all outliers for all numerical columns with `np.nan` on an example data frame. The method is robust against [all dtypes](https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html) that pandas provides and can easily be applied to data frames with mixed types:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np                                     

# sample data of all dtypes in pandas (column 'a' has an outlier)         # dtype:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list(np.random.rand(8)) + [123456, np.nan],       # float64
                   'b': [0,1,2,3,np.nan,5,6,np.nan,8,9],                  # int64
                   'c': [np.nan] + list("qwertzuio"),                     # object
                   'd': [pd.to_datetime(_) for _ in range(10)],           # datetime64[ns]
                   'e': [pd.Timedelta(_) for _ in range(10)],             # timedelta[ns]
                   'f': [True] * 5 + [False] * 5,                         # bool
                   'g': pd.Series(list("abcbabbcaa"), dtype="category")}) # category
cols = df.select_dtypes('number').columns  # limits to a (float), b (int) and e (timedelta)
df_sub = df.loc[:, cols]


# OPTION 1: z-score filter: z-score < 3
lim = np.abs((df_sub - df_sub.mean()) / df_sub.std(ddof=0)) < 3

# OPTION 2: quantile filter: discard 1% upper / lower values
lim = np.logical_and(df_sub < df_sub.quantile(0.99, numeric_only=False),
                     df_sub > df_sub.quantile(0.01, numeric_only=False))

# OPTION 3: iqr filter: within 2.22 IQR (equiv. to z-score < 3)
iqr = df_sub.quantile(0.75, numeric_only=False) - df_sub.quantile(0.25, numeric_only=False)
lim = np.abs((df_sub - df_sub.median()) / iqr) < 2.22


# replace outliers with nan
df.loc[:, cols] = df_sub.where(lim, np.nan)
```

To drop all rows that contain at least one nan-value:

```
df.dropna(subset=cols, inplace=True) # drop rows with NaN in numerical columns
# or
df.dropna(inplace=True)  # drop rows with NaN in any column
```

Using pandas 1.3 functions:

- [`pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.quantile()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: To avoid dropping rows with NaNs in non-numerical columns use df.dropna(how='any', subset=cols, inplace=True)

Comment: I believe `np.logical_or` should be `np.logical_and` to work properly (option 2)

Comment: Thanks for an extremely helpful answer!  I appreciate the discussion of the pros and cons of the different approaches; I'm very new to thinking about stats, and this helps me immensely.

Answer (score 52):

This answer is similar to that provided by @tanemaki, but uses a `lambda` expression instead of `scipy stats`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

standard_deviations = 3
df[df.apply(lambda x: np.abs(x - x.mean()) / x.std() < standard_deviations)
   .all(axis=1)]
```

To filter the DataFrame where only ONE column (e.g. 'B') is within three standard deviations:

```
df[((df['B'] - df['B'].mean()) / df['B'].std()).abs() < standard_deviations]
```

See here for how to apply this z-score on a rolling basis: [Rolling Z-score applied to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596912/rolling-z-score-applied-to-pandas-dataframe/59597003#59597003)

Comment: Hi, could you take a look at this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70954791/identifying-statistical-outliers-with-pandas-groupby-and-reduce-rows-into-diffe

Answer (score 45):

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# accept a dataframe, remove outliers, return cleaned data in a new dataframe
# see http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section1/prc16.htm
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def remove_outlier(df_in, col_name):
    q1 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3-q1 #Interquartile range
    fence_low  = q1-1.5*iqr
    fence_high = q3+1.5*iqr
    df_out = df_in.loc[(df_in[col_name] > fence_low) & (df_in[col_name] < fence_high)]
    return df_out
```

Comment: I am getting error "ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key" in line "    df_out = df_in.loc[(df_in[col_name] > fence_low) & (df_in[col_name] < fence_high)]
 " Will you help

Answer (score 31):

Since I haven't seen an answer that deal with *numerical* and *non-numerical* attributes, here is a complement answer.

You might want to drop the outliers only on numerical attributes (categorical variables can hardly be outliers).

**Function definition**

I have extended @tanemaki's suggestion to handle data when non-numeric attributes are also present:

```
from scipy import stats

def drop_numerical_outliers(df, z_thresh=3):
    # Constrains will contain `True` or `False` depending on if it is a value below the threshold.
    constrains = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]) \
        .apply(lambda x: np.abs(stats.zscore(x)) < z_thresh, reduce=False) \
        .all(axis=1)
    # Drop (inplace) values set to be rejected
    df.drop(df.index[~constrains], inplace=True)
```

**Usage**

```
drop_numerical_outliers(df)
```

**Example**

Imagine a dataset `df` with some values about houses: alley, land contour, sale price, ... E.g: [Data Documentation](http://jse.amstat.org/v19n3/decock/DataDocumentation.txt)

First, you want to visualise the data on a scatter graph (with z-score Thresh=3):

```
# Plot data before dropping those greater than z-score 3. 
# The scatterAreaVsPrice function's definition has been removed for readability's sake.
scatterAreaVsPrice(df)
```

[image: Before - Gr Liv Area Versus SalePrice]

```
# Drop the outliers on every attributes
drop_numerical_outliers(train_df)

# Plot the result. All outliers were dropped. Note that the red points are not
# the same outliers from the first plot, but the new computed outliers based on the new data-frame.
scatterAreaVsPrice(train_df)
```

[image: After - Gr Liv Area Versus SalePrice]

Comment: Great solution! As a heads up `reduce=False` has been deprecated since `pandas` version 0.23.0

Comment: Substitute `result_type='reduce'` for `reduce=False`.

Comment: @KeyMaker00 I'd really like to use this but I get the following error:    ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series

Answer (score 21):

For each series in the dataframe, you could use `between` and `quantile` to remove outliers.

```
x = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=200)) # with outliers
x = x[x.between(x.quantile(.25), x.quantile(.75))] # without outliers
```

Comment: Here you are selecting only data within the interquartile range (IQR), but keep in mind that there can be values outside this range that are not outliers.

Comment: Choosing e.g. 0.1 and 0.9 would be pretty safe I think. Using between and the quantiles like this is a pretty syntax.

Answer (score 15):

`scipy.stats` has methods `trim1()` and `trimboth()` to cut the outliers out in a single row, according to the ranking and an introduced percentage of removed values.

Comment: `trimboth` was easiest for me.

Answer (score 10):

If you like method chaining, you can get your boolean condition for all numeric columns like this:

```
df.sub(df.mean()).div(df.std()).abs().lt(3)
```

Each value of each column will be converted to `True/False` based on whether its less than three standard deviations away from the mean or not.

Comment: This should be `le(3)` since its _removing_ outliers. This way you get `True` for the outliers. Besides that +1 and this answer should be higher up

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to transform your data so that the effect of outliers is mitigated. You can do this by winsorizing your data.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import mstats
%matplotlib inline

test_data = pd.Series(range(30))
test_data.plot()
```

[image: Original data]

```
# Truncate values to the 5th and 95th percentiles
transformed_test_data = pd.Series(mstats.winsorize(test_data, limits=[0.05, 0.05])) 
transformed_test_data.plot()
```

[image: Winsorized data]

Answer (score 7):

You can use boolean mask:

```
import pandas as pd

def remove_outliers(df, q=0.05):
    upper = df.quantile(1-q)
    lower = df.quantile(q)
    mask = (df < upper) & (df > lower)
    return mask

t = pd.DataFrame({'train': [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9],
                  'y': [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0]})

mask = remove_outliers(t['train'], 0.1)

print(t[mask])
```

output:

```
   train  y
2      2  0
3      3  1
4      4  1
5      5  0
6      6  0
7      7  1
8      8  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I am in a very early stage of my data science journey, I am treating outliers with the code below.

```
#Outlier Treatment

def outlier_detect(df):
    for i in df.describe().columns:
        Q1=df.describe().at['25%',i]
        Q3=df.describe().at['75%',i]
        IQR=Q3 - Q1
        LTV=Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
        UTV=Q3 + 1.5 * IQR
        x=np.array(df[i])
        p=[]
        for j in x:
            if j < LTV or j>UTV:
                p.append(df[i].median())
            else:
                p.append(j)
        df[i]=p
    return df
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the 98th and 2nd percentile as the limits of our outliers

```
upper_limit = np.percentile(X_train.logerror.values, 98) 
lower_limit = np.percentile(X_train.logerror.values, 2) # Filter the outliers from the dataframe
data[‘target’].loc[X_train[‘target’]>upper_limit] = upper_limit data[‘target’].loc[X_train[‘target’]<lower_limit] = lower_limit
```

Answer (score 2):

a full example with data and 2 groups follows:

Imports:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
#pandas config
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 20)
```

Data example with 2 groups: G1:Group 1.  G2: Group 2:

```
TESTDATA = StringIO("""G1;G2;Value
1;A;1.6
1;A;5.1
1;A;7.1
1;A;8.1

1;B;21.1
1;B;22.1
1;B;24.1
1;B;30.6

2;A;40.6
2;A;51.1
2;A;52.1
2;A;60.6

2;B;80.1
2;B;70.6
2;B;90.6
2;B;85.1
""")
```

Read text data to pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=";")
```

Define the outliers using standard deviations

```
stds = 1.0
outliers = df[['G1', 'G2', 'Value']].groupby(['G1','G2']).transform(
           lambda group: (group - group.mean()).abs().div(group.std())) > stds
```

Define filtered data values and the outliers:

```
dfv = df[outliers.Value == False]
dfo = df[outliers.Value == True]
```

Print the result:

```
print '\n'*5, 'All values with decimal 1 are non-outliers. In the other hand, all values with 6 in the decimal are.'
print '\nDef DATA:\n%s\n\nFiltred Values with %s stds:\n%s\n\nOutliers:\n%s' %(df, stds, dfv, dfo)
```

Answer (score 2):

My function for dropping outliers

```
def drop_outliers(df, field_name):
    distance = 1.5 * (np.percentile(df[field_name], 75) - np.percentile(df[field_name], 25))
    df.drop(df[df[field_name] > distance + np.percentile(df[field_name], 75)].index, inplace=True)
    df.drop(df[df[field_name] < np.percentile(df[field_name], 25) - distance].index, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to clip rather than drop.  the following will clip inplace at the 2nd and 98th pecentiles.

```
df_list = list(df)
minPercentile = 0.02
maxPercentile = 0.98

for _ in range(numCols):
    df[df_list[_]] = df[df_list[_]].clip((df[df_list[_]].quantile(minPercentile)),(df[df_list[_]].quantile(maxPercentile)))
```

Answer (score -4):

Deleting and dropping outliers I believe is wrong statistically. 
It makes the data different from original data.
Also makes data unequally shaped and hence best way is to reduce or avoid the effect of outliers by log transform the data.
This worked for me:

```
np.log(data.iloc[:, :])
```

Comment: Can't make assumptions about why the OP wants to do something.