# Pandas: Filter dataframe for values that are too frequent or too rare

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, selection

On a pandas dataframe, I know I can groupby on one or more columns and then filter values that occur more/less than a given number.

But I want to do this on every column on the dataframe. I want to remove values that are too infrequent (let's say that occur less than 5% of times) or too frequent. As an example, consider a dataframe with following columns: `city of origin, city of destination, distance, type of transport (air/car/foot), time of day, price-interval`.

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import numpy as np
vals = [(c, np.random.choice(list(string.lowercase), 100, replace=True)) for c in 
    'city of origin', 'city of destination', 'distance, type of transport (air/car/foot)', 'time of day, price-interval']
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(vals))
>> df.head()
    city of destination     city of origin  distance, type of transport (air/car/foot)  time of day, price-interval
0   f   p   a   n
1   k   b   a   f
2   q   s   n   j
3   h   c   g   u
4   w   d   m   h
```

If this is a big dataframe, it makes sense to remove rows that have spurious items, for example, if `time of day = night` occurs only 3% of the time, or if `foot` mode of transport is rare, and so on.

I want to remove all such values from all columns (or a list of columns). One idea I have is to do a `value_counts` on every column, `transform` and add one column for each value_counts; then filter based on whether they are above or below a threshold. But I think there must be a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at sklearn feature detection

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This procedure will go through each column of the DataFrame and eliminate rows where the given category is less than a given threshold percentage, shrinking the DataFrame on each loop.

This answer is similar to that provided by @Ami Tavory, but with a few subtle differences:

- It normalizes the value counts so you can just use a percentile threshold.
- It calculates counts just once per column instead of twice. This results in faster execution.

Code:

```
threshold = 0.03
for col in df:
    counts = df[col].value_counts(normalize=True)
    df = df.loc[df[col].isin(counts[counts > threshold].index), :]
```

Code timing:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(string.lowercase), [1e6, 4], replace=True), 
                   columns=list('ABCD'))

%%timeit df=df2.copy()
threshold = 0.03
for col in df:
    counts = df[col].value_counts(normalize=True)
    df = df.loc[df[col].isin(counts[counts > threshold].index), :]

1 loops, best of 3: 485 ms per loop

%%timeit df=df2.copy()
m = 0.03 * len(df)
for c in df:
    df = df[df[c].isin(df[c].value_counts()[df[c].value_counts() > m].index)]

1 loops, best of 3: 688 ms per loop
```

Comment: you should edit `for col in df` to: `for col in df.columns`

Comment: Other way around (you don't need to specify `.columns`). Thanks for pointing out the inconsistency.

Comment: It seems like normalized value counts returns absolute z-scores of counts. Is there a way I can get negative normalized counts so I can be able to filter values for just "too much" or "too few" ones and not both?

Comment: @emremrah `normalize` returns relative frequencies, not z-scores.  These relative frequencies are non-negative and add up to 100%.  Just sort on these normalized values to get "too few"/"too much".

Answer (score 3):

I would go with one of the following:

**Option A**

```
m = 0.03 * len(df)
df[np.all(
    df.apply(
        lambda c: c.isin(c.value_counts()[c.value_counts() > m].index).as_matrix()), 
    axis=1)]
```

---

Explanation:

- `m = 0.03 * len(df)` is the threshold (it's nice to take the constant out of the complicated expression)
- `df[np.all(..., axis=1)]` retains the rows where some condition was obtained across all columns.
- `df.apply(...).as_matrix` applies a function to all columns, and makes a matrix of the results.
- `c.isin(...)` checks, for each column item, whether it is in some set.
- `c.value_counts()[c.value_counts() > m].index` is the set of all values in a column whose count is above `m`.

**Option B**

```
m = 0.03 * len(df)
for c in df.columns:
    df = df[df[c].isin(df[c].value_counts()[df[c].value_counts() > m].index)]
```

The explanation is similar to the one above.

---

Tradeoffs:

- Personally, I find B more readable.
- B creates a new DataFrame for each filtering of a column; for large DataFrames, it's probably more expensive.

Comment: I found this in another SO thread (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23202269/228177):
df_f = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 2).all(axis=1)]
This filters all values that are 2 standard deviations away, using a z-score test. Your suggestions look similar too. Thanks

Comment: That is true - it is similar. FWIW, I think the answer there is what you should use, whereas the answer here is a strict answer to your question.

Comment: BTW, just to create a MWE, how does one create a series of random alphabets, or a set of alphabets? e.g., [A, A, A, B, Z, X, X, A]. You create numeric series by np.random.randn(10), but is there something similar for strings?

Comment: Would you mind if I edit it into the question? It would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Python and using Pandas. I came up with the following solution below. Maybe other people might have a better or more efficient approach.

Assuming your DataFrame is `DF`, you can use the following code below to filter out all infrequent values. Just be sure to update the `col` and `bin_freq` variable. `DF_Filtered` is your new filtered DataFrame.

```
# Column you want to filter
col = 'time of day'

# Set your frequency to filter out. Currently set to 5%  
bin_freq = float(5)/float(100)

DF_Filtered = pd.DataFrame()

for i in DF[col].unique():
    counts = DF[DF[col]==i].count()[col] 
    total_counts = DF[col].count()
    freq  = float(counts)/float(total_counts)

    if freq > bin_freq:
        DF_Filtered = pd.concat([DF[DF[col]==i],DF_Filtered])

print DF_Filtered
```

Answer (score 0):

DataFrames support `clip_lower(threshold, axis=None)` and `clip_upper(threshold, axis=None)`, which remove all values below or above (respectively) a certain threshhold.

Comment: Sorry, but this *truncates*, which is 1. completely different, and 2. applicable to numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

We can also replace all the rare categories with one label, say "Rare" and remove later if this doesn't add value to prediction.

```
# function finds the labels that are more than certain percentage/threshold
def get_freq_labels(df, var, rare_perc):    
    df = df.copy()
    tmp = df.groupby(var)[var].count() / len(df)
    return tmp[tmp > rare_perc].index


vars_cat = [val for val in data.columns if data[val].dtype=='O']
for var in vars_cat:
    # find the frequent categories
    frequent_cat = get_freq_labels(data, var, 0.05)
    # replace rare categories by the string "Rare"
    data[var] = np.where(data[var].isin(
        frequent_cat ), data[var], 'Rare')
```