# How to keep rows which have a value repeating n times and delete ones that dont

Tags: python

I have a dataframe in which RoomID appears more than in one row for each RoomID.

For example ,if RoomID has values i={1...1000} , then we have multiple 1's or 2's or...100's, represented as rows of course.

I want to remove the rows which have a RoomID that appears less than 20 times. In other words, if a room(represented by RoomID) isn't in the dataframe at least 20 times,i want it removed.

Some psuedocode i've written for clarification:

```
        for i in range(1000):
        if len(df[df['RoomID']==i]>20):
            #keep rows with RoomID==i
        else:
            #remove rows with RoomID=i
```

I'm new to python so please keep that in mind then answering.

I won't understand complicated python stuff. I've worked on these problems in R previously.

**Example:**

*Input Dataframe:*

RoomID  |  Color  ...

1        | blue

1         |black

1         |purple

2        | red

*Output dataframe for n=2(so we want all room ids that appear more than 2 times):*

RoomID|Color  ...

1|         blue

1 |        black

1  |       purple

Comment: Add sample input and sample output.  Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303946/pandas-filter-dataframe-for-values-that-are-too-frequent-or-too-rare) help? It sounds very similar (maybe you have to reduce the answer there) and is the first google hit for "filter out rows with rare entries in pandas"

Comment: @Nic3500 i added what the changes would look like on a very simple data frame