# Remove Outlier Row from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, outliers

What is the Efficient way to remove outlier from a pandas dataframe? 
I have a pandas dataframe where i need to remove outlier points from the dataframe.

```
 X1       X2              X3              X4
228.0   4474.91836735   3507.15151515   6625.0
77.0    468.0           582.0           549.0
160.0   9.0             3507.15151515   6625.0
36.0    250.0           3507.15151515   6625.0
52.0    3.0             3.0             223.0
78.0    998.0           3507.15151515   6625.0
```

I tried with the solution in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-pandas-dataframe)
but no points were removed. Even a sklearn implementation for the same will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really two problems here: 1) outlier detection, and 2) removing them from a dataframe.

Problem #2 is fairly straightforward. You can use something like this once you have detected outliers in your columns:

```
df = df[df.loc[:,'column_name'] < high_threshold]
df = df[df.loc[:,'column_name'] > low_threshold]
```

Now for #1, outlier detection methods vary widely. If you have just these 4 dimensions and not so much data, a [Median Absolute Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) approach might be sufficient with no need for sklearn.

Since I don't know your application, I'll point you to [this documentation on outlier detection in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html).