# How to find outliers within groups in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, outliers

I have a df which looks like the following:

| Group. | Score. |
| --- | --- |
| red | 34 |
| blue | 42 |
| green | 1000 |
| green | 34 |
| blue | 34 |
| red | 42 |

I would like to add a column onto this which specifies if the value is an outlier. If there were no groups then I would use something like:

`df['outliers'] = df[df[col] > df[col].mean() + 3 * df[col].std()]`

But how would I do this so it is within the groups?

Comment: look into the where clause for pandas. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-where/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking a Pandas Dataframe for Outliers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087534/checking-a-pandas-dataframe-for-outliers)

Comment: Almost but not quite. Because I have different groups I need to compare each value against the mean of that group, not against the mean of the whole column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```py
df["is_outlier"] = df.groupby("Group.").transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()).abs() > 3*x.std())
```

In each group, we take the distance of elements from the group mean and see if its absolute value exceeds 3 times std of the group.