# Filtering outliers from DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, filtering, outliers

I have a big problem filtering my data. I've read a lot here on stackoverflow and ion other pages and tutorials, but I could not solve my specific problem...
The first part of my code, where I load my data into python looks as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from arch import arch_model


spotmarket = pd.read_excel("./data/external/Spotmarket_dhp.xlsx", index=True)

r = spotmarket['Price'].pct_change().dropna()

returns = 100 * r
df = pd.DataFrame(returns)
```

The excel table has 43.000 values in one column and includes the hourly prices. I use this data to calculate the percentage change from hour to hour and the problem is, that there are sometimes big changes between 1000 to 40000%. The dataframe looks as follow:

```
df
Out[12]: 
              Price
1         20.608229
2         -2.046870
3          6.147789
4         16.519258
             ...
43827    -16.079874
43828     -0.438322
43829    -40.314465
43830   -100.105374
43831    700.000000
43832    -62.500000
43833 -40400.000000
43834      1.240695
43835     52.124183
43836     12.996778
43837    -17.157795
43838    -30.349971
43839      6.177924
43840     45.073701
43841     76.470588
43842      2.363636
43843     -2.161042
43844     -6.444781
43845    -14.877102
43846      6.762918
43847    -38.790036
[43847 rows x 1 columns]
```

I wanna exclude this outliers. I've tried different ways like calculating the `mean`and the `std` and exclude all values which are + and - three times the `std` away from the `mean`. It works for a small part of the data, but for the complete  data, the mean and std are both `NaN`. Has someone an idea, how I can filter my dataframe?

Comment: Do you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23200666/2901002) ?

Comment: @jezrael yes I've tried this, but it doesn't work. I'm not sure, but it could be, that I had a fault in my references...Can you give me maybe a code example with that approach?

Comment: hmmm, it loooks like some data dependent issue, so is possible share your data if not confidental? Need only Price column, another columns is possible remove

Comment: yes I can share them with you. Where can I provide  the data?

Comment: if no problem, sent it to my email in my profile

Comment: or share link to gdocs, dropbox...

Comment: I've sent the data via mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need filter by  percentiles by [`quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html):

```
r = spotmarket['Price'].pct_change() * 100

Q1 = r.quantile(.25)
Q3 = r.quantile(.75)
q1 = Q1-1.5*(Q3-Q1)
q3 = Q3+1.5*(Q3-Q1)

df = spotmarket[r.between(q1, q3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

may you should first discard all the values that are giving those fluctuations and then create the dataframe. One way is to use the `filter()`