# Python database-data cleaning/preparation

Tags: python, database, pandas, data-cleaning

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston 
import pandas as pd 
boston = load_boston() 
boston_df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data) 

columns = boston.feature_names 
boston_df.columns = columns 

boston_df.head()
```

this is the code to import my database. how can I substitute all the outliers of the columns "DIS" with the mean/median of the column??

Comment: this is my code. my question is:how can I substitute all the outliers of the columns "DIS" with the mean/median of the column??

Comment: from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import pandas as pd
boston = load_boston()
boston_df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)

columns = boston.feature_names
boston_df.columns = columns

boston_df.head()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect and exclude outliers in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23199796/5728060