# Resetting outliers in a timeseries dataframe to 3 SD

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics

**Domain: Python & Pandas**

I have a time series data frame which has the total number of customers for each day for the last 10 years.

**The columns are:**

- date
- total customers

There are outliers in my total customers column.

I wanted to reset the *outliers outside of 3 standard deviations above the mean* to a value as defined by the formula below.

Outlier which is above 3SD = Mean + 3 S.D.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.clip_upper()` method to limit values in the customers column to mean+3*sd.

```
m = df['total customers'].mean()
sd = df['total customers'].std()
df['total customers'] = df['total_customers'].clip_upper(m + 3*sd)
```

Here's the [documentation for `clip_upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_upper.html#pandas.Series.clip_upper).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply

Comment: This function does exactly what you are asking for. It replaces any values that exceed the 'clip' value with the 'clip' value. It does not remove anything.

Comment: Hey Craig, sorry to bother you again: 
What if I wanted to completely remove all the rows with outliers?

Comment: @zosh - That's a new question, but the answer is to use boolean indexing as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23200666/7517724