# Box Whisker Plot using seaborn does not show the box and whiskers

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to build a box and whisker plots with seaborn. With my min value at '-200,000' and max value at '1,400,000'. Both of these are the outliers. However i only get the graph somewhat similar to a scatter plot.

Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

pi_analysis = pd.read_excel(r'C:\PI\PI Analysis.xlsx',
                           sheet_name = 'Raw Data'
                           , header = 0
                           )
print(pi_analysis)
group_segement= pi_analysis[['Segment', 'TOTAL AMOUNT']].groupby('Segment').sum()

print(group_segement)
group_segement_mean= pi_analysis[['Segment', 'TOTAL AMOUNT']].groupby('Segment')
group_segement_mean.mean().head()
group_segement_mean.describe()

sns.boxplot(x="Segment", y="TOTAL AMOUNT",data=pi_analysis)
```

[image]

Attached is the image. Have tried to change the access. It did not work. Any suggestions how to display the box and whiskers.

New image after changing the scale.

[image]

This is code section. However it still does not give me the complete view.

```
ax=sns.boxplot(x='Segment',y='TOTAL AMOUNT',data=pi_analysis)
ax.set_ylim(-10*10^8,10*10^8)
```

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: What do you see if you remove those outliers and re-plot? It looks like the boxes _may_ just be compressed due to the scale of the data

Comment: @G.Anderson i made the change and still dont see any improvement. Is there a way i could change the scale  so they boxes do not get compressed.

Comment: @G.Anderson made the change to scale using this `ax=sns.boxplot(x='Segment', y='TOTAL AMOUNT',data=pi_analysis, linewidth = 2.5)
ax.set_ylim([-2*10^7,2*10^97)`. It does display the box. Is there a better way to do this.  because i am unable to view all the data point being plotted. Converting the access to millions or billions based on the max values in Y

Comment: My question is whether a boxplot is the right representation of your data. If your range and quartiles are such that you get the result that you did, then I would consider either engineering your data to remove the outliers, or find another representation that's more fitted to your purpose

Comment: @G.Anderson to find out the outliers i am trying the box plot and then wish to remove them from the data by creating a new dataframe. It is not possible for me to check over 40000 rows to figure out the outliers for each of the segment

Comment: It's up to you to decide what is or isn't an outlier. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-pandas-dataframe) is a discussion of removing outliers, or you can just remove all data over/under the max/min of segment 3

Comment: @G.Anderson Thanks for the link will have a look at removing the outlier and then see what pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compressed boxes you are seeing are a result of the extreme outliers being accommodated by the scaling. It's very easy to drop the outliers

Seaborn boxplots will take the matplotlib argument:

```
showfliers=False
```

This will result in plots of only the box and whiskers, with the outliers not shown.

The last line of your code would then be:

```
sns.boxplot(x="Segment", y="TOTAL AMOUNT",data=pi_analysis, showfliers=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @g-anderson was alluding in his comment, the boxplot is there, it's just too small for you to see. Consider the following code:

```
d = np.random.random(size=(100,))
d[0] = 100
d[-1] = -100

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.boxplot(data=d, orient='vertical')
```

[image]

If you want to see the boxplot, you could simply rescale the y-axis to a more relevant range:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.boxplot(data=d, orient='vertical')
ax.set_ylim(-1,2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have made changes to my scale. The image has been added in the question. However the entire box still does not get displayed.

Comment: any way to fix it? i have tried the 2 answers here but still no box plot is showing