# How can I determine and remove outliers found by boxplot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, boxplot

I want to remove the outliers which are found by boxplot in my dataframe for each column. I know boxplot finds the outliers by IQR rule and displays them on graph. I know how to plot the boxplot using seaborn but I am unsure how can I determine exactly which rows these outliers actually refer to and how can I remove them ? Is there a function/method do to this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-pandas-data-frame

Answer (score 3):

According to the basic definition of IQR outliers,
Values less than Q1-1.5*IQR and values greater that Q3+1.5*IQR are treated as outliers. 
So,

```
Q1 =  df['col_name'].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df['col_name'].quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
```

Now,
outliers are ,

```
df[(df['col_name'] < Q1-1.5*IQR ) | (df['col_name'] > Q3+1.5*IQR)]['col_name']
```