# how to ignore NaN values in outlier detection

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

I have 6 columns dataframe, index is part numbers and all columns have numeric and NaN values.

I tried below code which I found in here as well;

```
jan_p2 = jan_p[(np.abs(stats.zscore(jan_p))<3).all(axis=1)]
```

link is;
[Detect and exclude outliers in Pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-pandas-data-frame)

But it doesn't work with missing values.
While creating the dataframe with pd.pivot I used fill_method=0 but it creates a bias in data.

I may try to handle data column by column with dropna() method but I guess there would be a much elegant way to do that.

Thanks in advance.