# Detecting outliers within one column for ranges of rows

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

In given data frame I have these two columns:

```
 neighbourhood_group
 price
```

Price column contains all the prices for all neighbourhood_group:

```
    neighbourhood_group price
 0  Brooklyn            149
 1  Manhattan           225
 2  Manhattan           150
 3  Brooklyn            89
 4  Manhattan           80
 5  Manhattan           200
 6  Brooklyn            60
 7  Manhattan           79
 8  Manhattan           79
 9  Manhattan           150
```

I am trying to detect outliers withing each neighbourhood_group.

The only idea I have come up to so far is to group by prices by neighbourhood_group, detect outliers within each group and create a mask for rows that needs to be dropped.

```
 data.groupby('neighbourhood_group')['price']
```

I suspect there might be an easier solution for that.

Comment: In this case none of your values are outliers right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Groupby.apply` and then get all the values which are outside the range of `3 * std` while substracting each value with the `mean`:

```
m = df.groupby('neighbourhood_group')['price'].apply(lambda x: x.sub(x.mean()).abs() <= (x.std()*3))

df[m]
```

**Output**

```
  neighbourhood_group  price
0            Brooklyn    149
1           Manhattan    225
2           Manhattan    150
3            Brooklyn     89
4           Manhattan     80
5           Manhattan    200
6            Brooklyn     60
7           Manhattan     79
8           Manhattan     79
9           Manhattan    150
```

**note**: in this case we get all the rows back, since there are no outliers.

Comment: there's an issue with your solution. You define outlier only if it's 3 std below the mean. What if it 3std above the mean? (also your output of m should be true/false)

Comment: @adhg: that is where the `abs()` comes in.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem ok, I might be wrong here but the mean (should be) always positive so the abs doesn't provide much. no? the sub may be confuses me here.

Comment: @adhg: it is not the `mean` over which you `.abs()` it is the `x.sub(x.mean())` (so the difference between the mean and the `x`.

Comment: if the value is `2` and mean is `5` what does `2-5` give? and what does `abs(2-5)` give. You basically just want the distance of observation to the mean, negative or positive does not matter @adhg

Comment: @ Erfan thanks for the clarification. I got it now. I see where the abs applies on. Roger Roger :-)

Comment: Thanks @Erfan. You right, shown snippet of values does not contain outliers. Your solution is most elegant and worked wonders, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think using groupby makes perfectly sense. I would then get the single groups, using get_group method for example. Finally you can do any analysis you need, see this example in case you missed it

[Detect and exclude outliers in Pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-pandas-data-frame)

Cheers and good work, I'll follow the question as I'm interested too

Comment: respectfully, you're not providing any solution to the OP.  I would strongly suggest you to provide your own work for the problem and not a link. (I'm quite sure Gara googled it before)

Answer (score 1):

I'll do it a bit manually:

let's assume your df is this (note I added 2 lines at the bottom)

```
    neighbourhood_group price
0   Brooklyn    149
1   Manhattan   225
2   Manhattan   150
3   Brooklyn    89
4   Manhattan   80
5   Manhattan   200
6   Brooklyn    60
7   Manhattan   79
8   Manhattan   79
9   Manhattan   150
10  Manhattan   28
11  Manhattan   280
```

let's add 2 column to facilitate here:

```
df['mean']=df.groupby('neighbourhood_group').transform('mean')
df['std'] = df.groupby('neighbourhood_group')['price'].transform('std')
```

let's ask for true/false if is_outlier

```
df['is_outlier'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['price']+x['std']<x['mean'] or x['price']-x['std']>x['mean'], axis=1)
```

result

```
    neighbourhood_group price   mean              std   is_outlier
0   Brooklyn            149     99.333333   45.390895   True
1   Manhattan           225     141.222222  82.308532   True
2   Manhattan           150     141.222222  82.308532   False
3   Brooklyn            89      99.333333   45.390895   False
4   Manhattan           80      141.222222  82.308532   False
5   Manhattan           200     141.222222  82.308532   False
6   Brooklyn            60      99.333333   45.390895   False
7   Manhattan           79      141.222222  82.308532   False
8   Manhattan           79      141.222222  82.308532   False
9   Manhattan           150     141.222222  82.308532   False
0   Manhattan           28      141.222222  82.308532   True
1   Manhattan           280     141.222222  82.308532   True
```

Also: note by @Willem Van Onsem the definition of an 'outlier' is usually 3 sigma above/below the mean. Consider this in your work and you can define your deviation from the mean (I used std=1)

Comment: Minor remark: in statistics, usually something is defined an outlier if there are three std.s or more between the mean and the value.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem.  3 sigma - correct- I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for thinking over the problem @adhg. It worked too