# pandas dataframe remove outliers from subgroup of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, outliers

I have a dataframe with 50 numerical columns and 10 categorical columns.

```
df = C1 C2 .. C10 N1 N2 ... N50
     a  b      c   2 3      1
```

I want to remove all outliers, but only from columns `N1,N2,N6,N8,N10`.
Meaning I wnt to keep all wors that are not outliers in any of this columns.
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: what you mean outliers ?

Comment: @YOBEN_S let's say 3 std above/below mean

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-pandas-data-frame

Comment: @M-Wi no because I only want to filter by sub-group of the columns

Comment: At least a few of the answers on that thread involve specifying the columns for filtration.

Comment: @M-Wi I saw an answer for specific column - I want for several columns and to avoid a loop

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you edited those specific requirements into your question. As it is, you're asking for the "best" way, which may be a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of these:

1) selecting and dropping rows in a cycle:

```
test_cols = ['N1','N2','N6','N8','N10']

for c in test_cols:
    drop_rows = df[(((df[c] - df[c].mean()) / df[c].std()).abs() < 3)].index
    df = df.drop(drop_rows)
```

2) combine `drop_rows` indices and drop all of the at once:

```
drop_set = {}
for c in test_cols:
    drop_ind = df[(((df[c] - df[c].mean()) / df[c].std()).abs() < 3)].index
    drop_set = {*drop_set, *drop_ind}
df = df.drop(drop_set)
```

3) have a complex selection condition and drop selected rows at once. Or .

```
drop_rows = df[(((df['N1'] - df['N1'].mean()) / df['N1'].std()).abs() < 3) |
               (((df['N2'] - df['N2'].mean()) / df['N2'].std()).abs() < 3) |
               (((df['N6'] - df['N6'].mean()) / df['N6'].std()).abs() < 3) |
               (((df['N8'] - df['N8'].mean()) / df['N8'].std()).abs() < 3) |
               (((df['N10'] - df['N10'].mean()) / df['N10'].std()).abs() < 3)].index
df = df.drop(drop_rows)
```

2) and 3) should be faster than 1)

Comment: @Rusian Isn't a way to do it without loop? won't it be more elegant?

Comment: if 'N1','N2','N6','N8','N10' were booleans, then a nice clean solution is possible with `any()` function.

To avoid cycle, you can use complex condition. See my answer updated.

Accept?