# Deleting entire rows of a dataset for outliers found in a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outliers

I am currently trying to remove the outlier values from my dataset, using the median absolute deviation method.

To do so, I followed the instructions given by @tanemaki in [Detect and exclude outliers in Pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-pandas-data-frame), which enables the deletion of entire rows that hold at least one outlier value.

In the post I linked, the same question was asked, but was not answered.

The problem is that **I only want the outliers to be searched in a single column**.

So, for example, my dataframe looks like:

```py
          Temperature    Date       
    1        24.72        2.3        
    2        25.76        4.6        
    3        25.42        7.0        
    4        40.31        9.3        
    5        26.21       15.6
    6        26.59       17.9
```

For example, there are two 'anomalies in the data:

- The Temperature value in row [4]
- The Date value in row [5]

So, **what I want is for the outlier function to only 'notice' the anomaly in the Temperature column, and delete its corresponding row.**

The outlier code I am using is:

```
df=pd.read_excel(r'/home/.../myfile.xlsx')
from scipy import stats
df[pd.isnull(df)]=0
dfn=df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df))<4).all(axis=1)] #@taneski
print(dfn)
```

And my resulting data frame currently looks like:

```py
          Temperature    Date       
    1        24.72        2.3        
    2        25.76        4.6        
    3        25.42        7.0               
    6        26.59       17.9
```

In case I am not getting my message across, the **desired output** would be:

```py
          Temperature    Date       
    1        24.72        2.3        
    2        25.76        4.6        
    3        25.42        7.0  
    5        26.21       15.6         
    6        26.59       17.9
```

Any pointers would be of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always limit the `stats.zscore` operation on only the `Temperature` column instead of the whole `df`. Like this maybe:

```
In [573]: dfn = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df['Temperature']))<4)]                                                                                                                                             

In [574]: dfn                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[574]: 
   Temperature  Date
1        24.72   2.3
2        25.76   4.6
3        25.42   7.0
5        26.21  15.6
6        26.59  17.9
```

Comment: How would you go about doing the same, but in the basis of finding outliers for two columns instead of one? I tried by (['Temperature'],['Date']) and had no luck there. Thanks!

Comment: You can do this: `df[(df['Temperature'] < 4) & df['Date'] == '2020-05-20')]`. This will the dataframe based on both conditions.

Comment: Is the solution in your original answer conditional to the situation or something?
 I am trying to use it for another spreadsheet which has a higher number of columns and it does not work (I edited the post with the problem)

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, you're calculating the zscores for the whole dataframe and then filtering the dataframe with those calculated scores; what you want to do is just apply the same idea to one column.

Instead of

```py
dfn=df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df))<4).all(axis=1)]
```

You want to have

```py
df[np.abs(stats.zscore(df["Temperature"])) < 4]
```

As a side note, I found that I was unable to get your example results by comparing the zscores to 4; I had to switch it down to 2.

Comment: Is the solution in your answer conditional to the situation or something? I am trying to use it for another spreadsheet which has a higher number of columns and it does not work (I edited the post with the problem)