# How to redistribute outliers over the previous time period?

Tags: pandas

Imagine a dataframe that looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
50
16
17
```

Normally we would apply an algorithm from [Detect and exclude outliers in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-a-pandas-dataframe) to entirely remove the 50, however my particular dataset instead requires me to distribute the values of the 50 over the previous 7 days:

```
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
```

How can I make this work in Pandas? I can detect the outliers pretty easily but not sure how to spread the values out into previous days. Note that a simple moving average doesn't work well for this type of data, as there would still be a jump in the average value when `50` shows up. What I need to do is smooth out 50 into the previous days so that no jump is visible.

Comment: Why your input dataframe has a length of 11 and your output 10? Where is 1? Can you update your dataframe with a more complete input and output example, please?

Comment: @Corralien you're right, updated

Comment: How do you choose 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9 and 8 (8 values not 7)

Comment: @Corralien once I see 50, I want to add 50/7 to all previous days and set the current value to what it should've been if we assume that the values keep increasing/decreasing at the same rate.

Comment: @Corralien basically imagine we have two data streams: one is measuring things on a daily basis and one dumps new datapoints at random periods of time as a big chunk. We want to acknowledge this new data but also avoid a jump in the graph.