# pandas dataframe how to replace extreme outliers for all columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, outliers

I have a pandas dataframe with some very extreme value - more than 5 std.
I want to replace, per column, each value that is more than 5 std with the max other value.
For example,

```
df = A B
     1 2
     1 6
     2 8
     1 115
     191 1
```

Will become:

```
df = A B
     1 2
     1 6
     2 8
     1 8
     2 1
```

What is the best way to do it without a for loop over the columns?

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: In this particular case, the last row is "only" ~2.3 the std of the column, you should better explain your criterion for exclusion ;)

Comment: @piterbarg in the link they find the outlier but how I replace its value, instead of filter it?

Comment: @mozway not sure what u meant? it is more than 2.3std? but anyway I changed

Comment: doesn't change much, the issue is that a single extreme value can bias the deviation, please provide the calculations for the exclusion, you'll realize what I mean

Comment: @mozway got it, good point. So what should be the best way to detect extreme outlier w/o be biased by the outlier itself?

Comment: that's the thing, there is no "best way", there are [dozen of ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection), this is an entire field so you need to test existing methods and see if it meets your expectations with your use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s=df.mask((df-df.apply(lambda x: x.std() )).gt(5))#mask where condition applies
s=s.assign(A=s.A.fillna(s.A.max()),B=s.B.fillna(s.B.max())).sort_index(axis = 0)#fill with max per column and resort frame

    A    B
0  1.0  2.0
1  1.0  6.0
2  2.0  8.0
3  1.0  8.0
4  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: I do not think the condition is quite right, it says x - standard_deviation(x) > 5 is an outlier?  works in this case but as a general rule for outlier detection it is quite poor. Eg for a column [100,...,100] it will mark all elements as outliers

Comment: @piterbarg and you may be right. However, I assume OP knows want he wants. I do not not what dataset he has. I answered the question literally. I didn't think I needed to read the question beyond the info he has provided. With your comment, he can edit the question and I can re do my answer if needed

Comment: I agree that your solution implements OPs request taken literally, but probably not what he really wants

Answer (score 0):

Calculate a column-wise z-score (if you deem something an outlier if it lies outside a given number of standard deviations of the column) and then calculate a boolean mask of values outside your desired range

```
def calc_zscore(col):
   return (col - col.mean()) / col.std()

zscores = df.apply(calc_zscore, axis=0)
outlier_mask = zscores > 5
```

After that it's up to you to fill the values marked with the boolean mask.

```
df[outlier_mask] = something
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the discussion in the comments you need to decide what your threshold is. say it is q=100, then you can do

```
q = 100
df.loc[df['A'] > q,'A'] = max(df.loc[df['A'] < q,'A'] )
df
```

this fixes column A:

```
    A   B
0   1   2
1   1   6
2   2   8
3   1   115
4   2   1
```

do the same for B