# Remove outlier from multiple lists in python

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and am working on plotting a graph with matplotlib with values from a csv and am trying to figure out the **most efficient way to remove outliers from my lists**. The CSV has three variables, `x, y, z`, which I've put into separate lists.

I want to find the **standard deviation** of each list and remove each point that is `< or > 2x` stdev (remove the point from each list - `x, y, z`, not just one list).

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to efficiently remove a point that is represented in three separate lists while making sure that I don't mix up different data points.

Do I use while loop and delete the value at a certain position for each variable? If so, how would I reference the position in the list where then number is larger than 2x stdev? Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import statistics as stat

#making list of each variable
x = []
y = []
z = []

with open('fundata.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    
    #skip the header line in CSV
    next(plots)

#import each variable from the CSV file into a list as a float
    for row in plots:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))
        z.append(float(row[2]))


#cleaning up the data
stdev_x = stat.stdev(x)
stdev_y = stat.stdev(y)
stdev_z = stat.stdev(z)

print(stdev_x)
print(stdev_y)
print(stdev_z)



#making the graph
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#make a scatter plot graphing x by y with z variable as color, size of each point is 3
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=3)

#Set chart title and label the axes
ax.set_title("Heatmap of variables", fontsize = 18)
ax.set_xlabel("Var 1", fontsize = 14)
ax.set_ylabel("Var 2", fontsize = 14)

#open Matplotlib viewer
plt.show()
```

Data set is as follows but is ~35000 rows long with more variability:

| var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3876514 | 3875931 | 3875846 |
| 3876515 | 3875931 | 3875846 |
| 3876516 | 3875931 | 3875846 |

Answer (score 1):

It is nearly always easier to use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html) to deal with data of this kind. Calculate the row-wise means and standard deviations, then select values within the required range. The outliers will be replaced with missing values. You can then use `dropna` to drop all the rows that contain missing values.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("fundata.csv", names=["x", "y", "z"])
mean = df.mean(axis=0)
std = df.std(axis=0)
edited = df[(mean - 2 * std <= df) & (df <= mean + 2 * std)].dropna()
```

Alternatively, use [scipy.stats.zscore](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html), which will [do the calculation for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-a-pandas-dataframe):

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
...
edited = df[(abs(zscore(df)) <= 2).all(axis=1)]
```

If you want to avoid `pandas` for some reason, then one way would be to replace all the outliers within each column with `None`:

```
def replace_outliers(values):
    mean = statistics.mean(values)
    stdev = statistics.stdev(values)
    for v in values:
        if mean - 2 * stdev <= v <= mean + 2 * stdev:
            yield v
        else:
            yield None

x, y, z = [replace_outliers(column) for column in [x, y, z]]
```

Then zip the columns together and select rows that do not contain `None`:

```
selected_rows = [row for row in zip(x, y, z) if not None in row]
```

Finally if needed you can zip the rows together to transpose the data back into three column lists:

```
x, y, z = zip(*selected_rows)
```