# Detect outliers using IQR and remove them using the zscore

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, outliers

I had calculated the percentage of outliers in my dataset using the IQR method and I got the next result:

[image]

I want to remove outliers for Wind Speed and Pressure using z1 score is that possible?

I got my data set from the next site: [my data](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/budincsevity/szeged-weather) and I used the next function to calculate the outliers percentage:

```
def outlier_percent(data):
    Q1 = data.quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = data.quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    minimum = Q1 - (1.5 * IQR)
    maximum = Q3 + (1.5 * IQR)
    num_outliers =  np.sum((data < minimum) |(data > maximum))
    num_total = data.count()
    return (num_outliers/num_total)*100
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data?

Comment: what's the point of detecting outliers with iqr but removing them with z-score?

Comment: I want to know if the outliers are the same for each method means points detect as outliers with IQR are going to be detected the same with Score

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199796/detect-and-exclude-outliers-in-a-pandas-dataframe