# How can I write a loop to discard values that are too far from the mean value?

Tags: python, loops, intervals

In my code I input some data points and it outputs an array of intervals between the data points: For example, `[92 97 97 99 99 99 97 97 98 97 99 98 95]`

If there is a value that is 20% less or greater than the mean of the intervals, I want it to print 'Intervals are irregular'.  If there is not a value that is 20% less or greater than the mean of the intervals, I want it to print 'intervals are not irregular'.

I calculate the mean of the values in this way:

```
averageinterval = np.mean(intervals)
```

Then I tried to write a for loop:

```
for interval in intervals:
    if interval is 20% > averageinterval:
        print('intervals are irregular')
```

This gives a syntax error.  How can I correctly write this loop?

Comment: Could you define what you mean by `mean of the intervals`?

Comment: so a mean is when you add up all the numbers and then divide by how many numbers there are. The intervals are [92 97 ..... 98 95]. Hence the mean will be 97.23 (2dp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def check_regularity(intervals):
    average = intervals.mean()
    regular = all(intervals < average * 1.2) and all(intervals > average * 0.8)
    print(f'The intervals are {"not " * regular}irregular.')

check_regularity(np.array([92, 97, 97, 99, 99, 99, 97, 97, 98, 97, 99, 98, 95]))
check_regularity(np.array([92, 97, 37, 99, 99, 99, 97, 97, 98, 97, 99, 98, 95]))
```

Output:

```
The intervals are not irregular.
The intervals are irregular.
```

If you just want to extract the values that are within that range, then you should do this:

```
average = intervals.mean()
regular_intervals = intervals[(intervals < average * 1.2) & (intervals > average * 0.8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is additional information: It seems to me you might be looking for outlier checks. If this is the case: You probalbly want something that tests for deviation of the MEDIAN value, because the mean would be affected too strongly by outliers: I can recommend [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354094/pythonic-way-of-detecting-outliers-in-one-dimensional-observation-data)
the answer by Joe Kington.

Comment: I think you mean outliers.

Answer (score -2):

There is no such thing as a percentage operator in Python, you will need to define a method that takes the percentage from averageinterval.

Example:

```
def percentage(part, whole):
  return float(part)/ float(whole) * 100
```