# Matplotlib boxplot, ignore outliers when *computing* median, etc.?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot, outliers

I know it's easy to do a boxplot in matplotib without visualizing the outliers, but it looks like the box plot itself is still computed using the outliers even when you don't display them.

Is there a way to generate the boxplot plot so the result is computed from the data NOT including the outliers?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: bp = ax.boxplot(data2plot, sym='')

Comment: The above will simply make outliers invisible. data2plot is just a list of lists, with each list containing the values each box and whisker are made from. I'd like to construct the box and whiskers for each list after ignoring the outliers.

Comment: Be careful with the underlying statistics. I would expect that removing some outliers will introduce new outliers in the new boxplot. Read [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882393/matplotlib-disregard-outliers-when-plotting).

Comment: You would need to remove the outliers from your data and then do the boxplot. As this changes your data, there is no predefined function to do that, as you are yourself responsible for manipulating the data.